# How to find the hidden pin?

Tags: proteus

I'm a starter to Proteus. My teacher told me to connect three modules: STM32, SIM800C, GPS Neo6M to make "simple gps circuit" like this: [image]

When I opened Proteus then added the modules in my library, I couldn't find the pin like VCC, 5V on STM32 module and VCC on SIM800C module (they don't have "hidden pins" too). I opened the datasheet too, but I couldn't see the pins, like the description in the "pinout diagram" of STM32: tm32duinoforum.com/forum/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/The-Generic-STM32F103-Pinout-Diagram.pdf
[image]

Here is the "preview" of STM32 and SIM800C in Proteus 8, I'm just a new learner and need step by step:
[image]

Comment: Guessing, never worked in Proteus, who ever created the library of these parts may have used multiple schematic symbols for each physical part. Or they may have done a bad job of it. I'd first look for more symbols or variations of the symbol.  Then I would consider downloading new libraries and trying those.

Comment: That 1st pic of yours is a bit misleading. It's labeled as the pinout diagram for a STM32F103, but it is in fact the diagram for a *module* which contains a STM32F103 IC. Does your teacher intent for you to use a module like in that pic, or a bare IC?

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem.

The STM32 you added in Proteus is not a module, it's the bare chip.

Your other picture shows a module which contains an STM32 plus all the other components needed around it to work, incuding power supply components.